# Changing working directory in a loop in Python 2.7

Tags: python, for-loop, active-directory, iteration

Good morning,
I am currently working on a code that reads files in several directories, but I don't really know how to do that. I've searched here before but didn't found the answer.

The folder structure inside a path(eg: /home/Documents/foamOutput) is like: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, and I need to access each of those folders, operate with the files inside them, and change to the following folder.

I'm pretty new with python, so any help is very welcome.

Kind regards,
Javier

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html in particular you might find `os.walk` useful

Comment: Thank you, I knew I had to use that function, but had no idea how to implement the `os.chdir` inside the loop. It is solved and the code working properly.